# What is the complexity of this double loop

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N = 32; /* for example */

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N*N; i = i*3)
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            sum++;

    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The outer loop is odd.

If the check was with just N (not N*N) then i incrementing by multiplication of 3 each time would mean would take n/3 iterations of N for outer loop?

But check is with N* N or N^2 so that implies will grow by

```
N^2  / 3 ??? (n squared divided by 3) Is that correct?
```

If I play around with different values of N, say doubling each time, the i loop (on its own) doesn't grow by much.  like logarithmic growth).  How would I express this mathematically?

Then how do you think about the inner loop? If it increments up to i each time how can I express that mathematically? How can I relate the inner loop to N?

I would like to a) be able to express the 'complexity' mathematically in terms of N. Then next step, b) is to use big-O notation.

Confused by this. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the external loop is executed `log3(N*N)` times, because every time you multiply by 3 so you have 1, 3, 9... and it takes logarithm base 3 of N*N executions to reach N*N.

The internal loop is executed at most N*N times, so everything becomes `log3(N*N)*N*N`.

Comment: You can't always approximate the total cost of an inner loop by assuming the worst case (here N*N) each time it's run. Usually doing so is logically incorrect but produces the correct complexity, but here it gives an overestimate.

Answer (score 0):

The increment instruction is (approximately) executed N*N + N*N/3 + N*N/9 + ... = N*N(1 + 1/3 + 1/9 + ...) = N*N*3/2 times (using the formula for a geometric series). So overall the code's runtime is O(N*N) (assuming all arithmetic is O(1) and C ints can represent arbitrarily large numbers).

Answer (score 0):

fede1024 is right that the outer loop is log3(n^2).

The inner loop is a little more complex but solving the summation of 1 + 8 + 27.. (sum x^3) gives you the solution. You could calculate the sum of cubes using a set of linear equations given that the sum is equal to a polynomial of degree 3 and expressed as ay^3 + by^2 + cy. Or Google it and find that the sum of cubes is equal to (n(n+1)/2)^2 (can include a full solution if you want).

Then the entire complexity would be log3(n^2)*(n(n+1)/2)^2. Big O notation, log3(n^2)*n^3. Could be wrong.